# How do I add a button to a search bar controller programmatically?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I got this code from a website detailing how to add a search bar such below. It is added to a tableView which then is updated with the results.

I was wondering how I could add a button to it so that it only searches when the user presses 'GO'. I need to do this because currently it's searching Parse but I believe Parse is searching and then changing its search as the user types a new character resulting in the results not always being 100% accurate. Any help would be appreciated.

```
lazy var resultSearchController = UISearchController()    

self.resultSearchController = ({
            let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
            controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()

            self.daTableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

            return controller
        })()
```